# Creating a Thumbnail through AudioVideoCaptureDevice

Tags: c#, image-processing, windows-phone-8

This is either very complicated or I am really bad!!

I am using `AudioVideoCaptureDevice` and I would like to create an image thumbnail of the video and save it into isolated storage.

So far what I have is the following:

```
    private void SaveThumbnail()
    {
        var w = (int)_videoCaptureDevice.PreviewResolution.Width;
        var h = (int)_videoCaptureDevice.PreviewResolution.Height;

        var argbPx = new int[w * h];

        Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => _videoCaptureDevice.GetPreviewBufferArgb(argbPx));

        var wb = new WriteableBitmap(w, h);
        argbPx.CopyTo(wb.Pixels, 0);
        wb.Invalidate();

        using (var isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            var fileName = _isoVideoFileName + ".jpg";

            if (isoStore.FileExists(fileName))
                isoStore.DeleteFile(fileName);

            var file = isoStore.CreateFile(fileName);
            wb.SaveJpeg(file, w, h, 0, 20);
            file.Close();
        }
    }
```

So the `GetPreviewBufferArgb()` method fills my int array with the image data (as the documentation states at least). How should I proceed to save those pixels into isolatedstorage so I could load them later on?

The above code doesn't seem to work since when I open the image from the IsolatedStorage it's not opening.

**UPDATE**: Now I am able to save something - unfortunately the image is always black (NO - I am not testing the application on the emulator)!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it to work - a bit wired though.. it seemed like the whole processes should be done in a UI thread.

```
        private void SaveThumbnail()
        {
            Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
            {
                var w = (int)_videoCaptureDevice.PreviewResolution.Width;
                var h = (int)_videoCaptureDevice.PreviewResolution.Height;

                var argbPx = new Int32[w * h];

                _videoCaptureDevice.GetPreviewBufferArgb(argbPx);
                var wb = new WriteableBitmap(w, h);
                argbPx.CopyTo(wb.Pixels, 0);
                wb.Invalidate();

                using (var isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
                {
                    var fileName = _isoVideoFileName + ".jpg";

                    if (isoStore.FileExists(fileName))
                        isoStore.DeleteFile(fileName);

                    var file = isoStore.CreateFile(fileName);
                    wb.SaveJpeg(file, w, h, 0, 20);
                    file.Close();
                }
            });
        }
```